# Unable to replace ° character

Tags: java, netbeans

I have

```
String test = "an°ther";
```

and I want to replace `°` with `o` but when I use

```
test.replaceAll("°", "o");
```

what I really run is `test.replaceAll("º", "o")` because that's what character goes into the IDE when I copy and paste it.

Is there a way to get the ASCII value or replace based on some other criteria?

Comment: are you talking of sourcecode replace in the IDE editor perspective or a running java application...?

Comment: Perhaps your IDE is not saving using an appropriate character set. You can see that your web browser and clipboard are not having that same trouble. You must save your source file in an encoding for a character set that includes the characters you use in the source. Given that Java source files are tokenized from Unicode characters (regardless of the file encoding), you might as well use one of the Unicode encodings.  UTF-8 is very common for files and streams. Ultimately, you, your IDE and your compiler, and your source control system, and your collaborators have to agree on the encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the unicode number of the ° sign ([Degree Sign](http://unicode-table.com/en/00B0/)): `U+00B0`. Also note that you don't need [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) (you're not using regex here, [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) is enough):

```
String test = "an°ther";
System.out.println(test.replace("\u00B0", "o"));
// another
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try unicode to replace the characters.

```
test.replace("\u00b0", "o");
```

You can read about Unicode in Wiki.